# Informal Acknowledgments

Tags: словоупотребление

In English we have many ways to respond to a question or statement.  What are some informal ways to do this in Russian other than да or нет?

Examples:
“Yep”, “Nope”
“Yea”, “Nah”
“Yay”, “Nay” (old English)

Answer (score 8):

Means "**Yes**":
Да. Ага. Угу. Аха. Так. Окей. Хорошо. Отлично. Так и быть. Согласен. Конечно! Бесспорно.

Means "**No**":
Нет. Не. Неа. Нетушки. Не пойдёт. Не согласен. Против. Ни за что. "Ага, конечно!" "Не дождётесь!" "Дудки!" Забудь об этом! Нёу. Отнюдь! Увы.

Comment: `нетушки` is good

Comment: is **нетушки** informal?

Comment: yes it is, it's mostly used for refusal and usually being said in conversation between good acquaintances because it kind of softens the refusal

Comment: Excellent set of examples! If you could match the translations with the closest usage/context it would be very helpful.  For example, which is most like “Yep”?

Answer (score 3):

"Да" can be replaced with "Ага" or "Угу", or sometimes "Так", or, when the question is about presence or existence of something, or the conversation is military-style - "Есть!"

"Нет" can be shortened to "Не", or, when the question is about presence or existence of something - "Нету".

Comment: Also add *ну*, which may mean both confirmation and reluctance, depending on intonation and pitch.

Answer (score 3):

Wishing to say `Да` sarcastically to mean `in fact no` when responding to a question or implicitly disagreeing with a statement one can pronounce it as `До-о-о`. With inquiring intonation `До-о-о?` means emphasized disbelief or fake amazement `oh really?`, `no shit`

A playful or encouraging way to say `Нет` is `Неа`

Just like in Ebonics `нет` can be expressed with interjection [`uh uh`](https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20160317/uh_uh--1_gb_1.mp3) which is reminiscent of `Неа`. Sadly Russian doesn't have a phonetic representation for it and i don't think it's formally or widely recognized as a valid semantic unit despite being in active use. I guess until it's put into writing it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

OT. In Russian, да AND нет can even complement each other. "Да, нет." - is an absolutely correct, complete sentence.

Comment: In "Да, нет" that да is not 'yes', it's a conjunction translated as "but", like in "Да я не знаю..."